# Pluriel de « libre à lui »

Tags: expressions, pluriel, locutions

Quel est le pluriel de « libre à lui » : « libres à eux » ou « libre à eux », et pourquoi ?

Je me rends compte que je ne comprends pas l'étymologie de cette locution, et je ne la trouve pas dans mes dictionnaires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La formule est une contraction de la forme plus complète :

> Il vous est libre de [+ action].

Ici, libre est équivalent à [loisible](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/loisible), qui a presque disparu*.

Extrait de la définition ([ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/libre), section I.B.1.b.β) :

> Tournure impersonnelle, vieillie. Il est libre à quelqu'un de + infinitif.
>   Il est permis, autorisé, loisible à quelqu'un de + infinitif. *Par ce traité, il est libre aux généraux vendéens de rester en France ou de passer en Angleterre (Chateaubr., Mél. hist.,1827, p. 342).*

Et on comprend donc mieux pourquoi *libre à eux* ne fait pas porter la marque du pluriel sur *libre*, dans la mesure où le sujet est le *il* impersonnel.

---

* Disparu ? ...quand même pas tout-à-fait. Un exemple tiré de *La solitude* (Ferré) :

> [...] Les flics du détersif vous indiqueront la case où il vous sera *loisible* de laver ce que vous croyez être votre conscience, et qui n'est qu'une dépendance de l'ordinateur neurophile qui vous sert de cerveau. [...]

Answer (score 18):

Libre à … de … est une une formule adverbale figée qui correspond à la construction

> est libre de + infinitif

Donc le pluriel de libre à lui est :

> Libre à eux

[Cet article](http://cyjung.com/spip.php?article740) donne la position de plusieurs dictionnaires, et notamment l'explication de Grevisse : la « formule averbale figée *Libre à … de …* » est invariable car elle correspond à la construction « il (lui) (vous) (leur) est libre de + infinitif ».

Answer (score 7):

C'est *libre à eux*.

L'adjectif *libre* ne qualifie pas le pronom *lui* ou *eux*, et ne s'accorde donc pas.

Comment: Oui, mais pourquoi ? Quelle est la construction grammaticale sous-jacente (aujourd'hui oubliée) ?

Answer (score 5):

« Libre » ne se rapporte pas à « lui » (comme le ferait un adjectif), donc je dirais « libre à eux ».